# Can't launch python script on boot (rpi)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I've tried many ways to launch a python while booting my raspberry pi.

No success.

in /etc/rc.local

I added`sudo /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/file.py &`

Not working

I've tried crontab-e `sudo crontab -e` and add `@reboot python3 /home/pi/file.py &`

Not working

I'm lost and any help would be nice (I've got poor skills but try to do my best)

Comment: This question would be better on http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: can you post python script?

Comment: I managed to run that script before. But I had to format my noobs card and now I can't...

Comment: Nobody can help me ?